# Encoding error after inserting C++ Code

Tags: unicode

I'm writing a small document with c++ code, right after inserting some new code I started receiving the following error when running: `pdflatex my_doc_name.tex`.

```
! Package inputenc Error: Invalid UTF-8 byte sequence.

See the inputenc package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
l.26 cout << "3. Sucesión
                           Numerica." << endl;
```

I tried using `\UseRawInputEncoding` but certain characters such as "ú" are not rendered in my document.

For a minimum example, here's part of my document, I'm also using nvim as my editor.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}
\date{Agosto 2021}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\section{Menú}


\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]

cout << "Programas Disponibles" << endl;
cout << "1. Calculador de Promedio" << endl;
cout << "2. Contador de Digitos." << endl;
cout << "3. Sucesión Numerica." << endl;

int programa;
cout << "Ingrese una opción: ";
cin >> programa;

switch(programa) {
    case 1:
        // Programa Calculador de promedio
        break;
    case 2:
        // Programa Contador de Digitos
        break;
    case 3:
        // Programa Susesión Numerica
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Esa no es una opción valida";
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

I just started learning Latex... hope this is not a duplicate D:

Comment: For consistency please copy the code into your question and include it in {} like your error message. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

If you use non-ascii chars in a listing, you should use the literate option of listings to declare replacements:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}
\date{Agosto 2021}

\lstset{
literate=
 {á}{{\'a}}1 
 {ã}{{\~a}}1 
 {é}{{\'e}}1 
 {ó}{{\'o}}1
 %extend the list as needed
 }
 
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\section{Menú}

Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts.

\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]

cout << "Programas Disponibles" << endl;
cout << "1. Calculador de Promedio" << endl;
cout << "2. Contador de Digitos." << endl;
cout << "3. Sucesión Numerica." << endl;

int programa;
cout << "Ingrese una opción: ";
cin >> programa;

switch(programa) {
    case 1:
        // Programa Calculador de promedio
        break;
    case 2:
        // Programa Contador de Digitos
        break;
    case 3:
        // Programa Susesión Numerica
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Esa no es una opción valida";
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there a complete list for those replacements (just for reference)? I already added `{ú}{{\'u}}1`

Answer (score 1):

Either add `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, which leaves a warning, or don't use both with no warning left, as indicated.

For more background see e.g. the Latex-Wikibooks, which you can also download: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX .

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%<<==
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{listings}

\title{Foo}
\author{Bar}
\date{Agosto 2021}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}

\section{Menú}

Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. Some text, to show the difference of fonts. 

\begin{lstlisting}[language=c++]

cout << "Programas Disponibles" << endl;
cout << "1. Calculador de Promedio" << endl;
cout << "2. Contador de Digitos." << endl;
cout << "3. Sucesión Numerica." << endl;

int programa;
cout << "Ingrese una opción: ";
cin >> programa;

switch(programa) {
    case 1:
        // Programa Calculador de promedio
        break;
    case 2:
        // Programa Contador de Digitos
        break;
    case 3:
        // Programa Susesión Numerica
        break;
    default:
        cout << "Esa no es una opción valida";
}
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}
```

**Result**:

[image: Menu-section as an example]

Comment: Thank you! I'm really excited to learn Latex, this is a small document I'm writing for a friend, so I though this would be a nice chance to try Latex out

Comment: Fine :) Yes, Latex has something addictive to it ... and it's easier to conquer with some basic background knowledge. Once you've grabbed the basic concepts, you can go in almost any direction to learn more. // Hint, some oppinion: Latex, like TeX, is for typesetting. For small documents you won't recognize the difference, but for larger text I suggest thinking about using a writing tool, to focus on content, logical presentation, turning vague ideas into Pulitzer-worthy text etc. (No, Word is not such a writing tool. To avoid advertising, have a look at my profile ...)

Comment: sorry but this is nonsense. you shouldn't remove T1-encoding, and inputenc with utf8 is unneeded in a current latex.

Comment: You are right, but it was the quickest way to compile without warnings in my environment. So, what's the correct solution, as the originators fails ... ?

Comment: see my answer, you need literate.

Comment: Sorry, I do not agree. But let's follow the rules and stop this discussion here. Thanks